# TeX capacity exceeded error when nesting multiple leftbars

Tags: errors, compilation-error

First of all, it is my first time using this platform, so forgive me for maybe not writing this question with the optimal format.

I am working on a project, and I have this idea where I want to nest multiple propositions and leftbars. It works when I don't nest a lot, but when there are too many (4 or 5), I receive this error: "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]". I also recieve some log warnings like this one: "Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 170".I don't really know about LaTeX, so when I need something, I search the answer online, and copy things that I don't know how they work. The first line of my log file is "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)"

This is more or less what I have done:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}

\newlength{\leftbarwidth}
\setlength{\leftbarwidth}{1pt}
\newlength{\leftbarsep}
\setlength{\leftbarsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{2pt}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{{{\vrule width \leftbarwidth\relax\hspace {\leftbarsep}}}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance \hsize -\width \FrameRestore }%
    
}{%
    \endMakeFramed
}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}
\begin{proposition}
My proposition
\begin{leftbar}
\begin{proposition}
My second proposition
...
\end{proposition}
\end{leftbar}
\end{proposition}
\end{leftbar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  More information is needed.  Please add a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem, so that potential helpers will have something to debug.  It would also be helpful to know what "flavor" and version of LaTeX you're using; this should be identified in the first line of your log file.

Comment: neither leftbar nor proposition environments are defined by default so unless you show a small complete example that shows the problem it is not easy to say anything about your issue.

Comment: Note there are no `proposition` envs defined by default, so your example still have not way of compiling. Why do you have a proposition inside a proposition in the first place. If all your propositions need to have a left bar then there much better ways to do this. See the `tcolorbox` package, it can even add decorations to existing envs like `proposition` (when you have defined it)